# Socket.io emit doesnt work

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Basically,

I first initiate socket.io like this:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(1337);
```

Then, after using http to get a POST request and check some info, I try this:

```
var updateArray = {timer:"start"};
jsonUpdate = JSON.stringify(updateArray);
io.emit('update', jsonUpdate);
```

But it doesn't send the sockets, and I really can't understand the socket.io documentation sadly, so I'd be happy if someone can help me out.

Server code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io')(1337);

var initialBomb = 0;

function now() {
    return Math.floor(new Date() / 1000);
}

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var body = "";
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        if (req.method == 'POST') {
            body += chunk;
        }
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
        if (parsedBody.round["bomb"] == "planted") {
            var rightNow = now();
            var initialCheck = initialBomb + 41;
            if (rightNow > initialCheck) {
                initialBomb = now();
                var updateArray = {timer:"start"};
                jsonUpdate = JSON.stringify(updateArray);
                io.emit('update', jsonUpdate);
                console.log(jsonUpdate);
            }
        }
    });
}).listen(3000);
```

Client Code:

```
<script>
            var socket = io('87.98.219.48:1337');
            socket.on('update', function(payload) {
                var data = JSON.parse(payload);
                console.log(payload);
                if (data['timer'] == 'start') {
                    initTick = timerNow();
                    setTimeout(tick, delay);
                }
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Who are you socketing? Where is your client code?  Is that all of your server code? If so that is your issue. If not, post it.

Comment: I'm trying to socket an HTML page, and no, I have an http createServer that listens to post requests, and upon a post request it sends the array in the emit.

Comment: Check out http://socket.io/docs/   You appear to be missing alot of required code.  Would be helpful if you post your client code.

Comment: Added my code in the OP.

Comment: Do you have socket.on('update') in your client?  var socket = io('http://localhost') ?

Comment: Added my client code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97913/discussion-between-ron-melkhior-and-gary).

Comment: What is this `var socket = io('IP:1337');` supposed to be?  You should be connecting to a same-origin URL in the client or an URL that has CORS support on the server.  `IP:1337` is not a valid URL.

Comment: I highly suggest taking a look at the chat tutorial to figure out where you are missing code http://socket.io/get-started/chat/ or just jump straight to the source of it on github https://github.com/rauchg/chat-example

Comment: @jfriend00 Obviously IP:1337 is the IP where the node.js script is hosted, I just don't want people to know the ip...

Comment: That wasn't obvious to me.  And it still isn't obvious to me whether you're putting the IP into a proper URL form or not.  Not using a legal URL with socket.io is one main reason it fails to connect for people.  Also, is your IP address a secret?  Mine sure isn't.  Every web server I visit knows it.

Comment: You make a point, edited it to what it actually is in the OP.

Comment: Try var socket = io('http:// 87.98.219.48:1337');  No spaces in there... Are you seeing errors in console?

Comment: That solved it, I feel so stupid now. Thank you so much :)